# How does one turn an object into fractal?

Tags: applications, fractals

I've seen a lot of digital art made using fractals e.g landscapes, flowers, trees and the like, but I was wondering how does one turn an object into a fractal?
Like say....if I wanted to make a fractal image of my cat, or house or neighbour  how would I go about that?

Comment: Are to talking about googles deep dream? in that case deepdreamgenerator.com/

Comment: There was an answer that was posted here previously and gave a link : http://www.statisticsblog.com/tag/fractal/      But the link didnt have what I wanted, nor is the dream generator very helpful, does anyone have a better answer?

Comment: Perhaps describe what you are after then?

Comment: Okay so basically the deep dream website says  that using their AI you can find specific objects in images. But I dont see how they are converting the image into fractals.Basically:     IMAGE--------------(process)--------------Fractal that looks like original image.     I'm interested in the "process" part of how that happens.That's all, I'm not interested in identifying objects in the image.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to construct a fractal resulting from the iteration of some linear contraction maps (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system). The reverse process is much more difficult, and is called "fractal compression" because it would describe a complex image by a (hopefully) small set of contraction maps. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_compression

Answer (score 0):

Construct an iterated function system, see for example the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system, that constructs the original image with on iteration from a simple geometric shape (such as line representing ground). Then iterate. The result is likely to be messy.